# Pattern in parental care behaviour from lower to higher animals?

Tags: zoology, ecology, behaviour

I was studying about parental care behavior. There seems a pattern present in this behavior in case of vertebrates. The more evolutionary advanced class the animal belongs to, the greater effort an animal gives to care its off spring?

Is it a real pattern?

My current thinking is that if the pattern is indeed real, it is because the more complex an animal is, it takes more time to get fit with the environment, so it takes more effort for parents to get them ready for the environment. Am I close?

Comment: What do you mean by evolutionary complexity/advanced-ness?

Comment: What would be reasons for this particular pattern (assuming it is generally applicable to animals of "increasing complexity", which you need to define) to exist? Traits don't exist in a vacuum, they are intimately connected to one another. What's different about the development of a snake vs. a mouse vs. a deer vs. a gorilla vs. a human?